# How to concatenate negative form of verbs to make use of the pattern ～て、～て、～します?

Tags: grammar

I want to say,

> For health, I don't smoke, don't drink alcohol too much, do much exercise.

Here is my attempt, but

> 健{けん}康{こう}のために、たばこを吸{す}わなくて、あまりお酒{さけ}を飲{の}まなくて、よく運{うん}動{どう}しています。

my teacher said it sounds weird but she has not explained to me why it is weird.

Could you help me to make it correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your sentence does sound awkward, if not terribly ungrammatical, for using 「～～なくて」 multiple times.  To me, it sounds "forced" or at least "translated" for the purpose of getting used to the negative te-form, but the way you used it is making the sentence sound unadultlike.

To "correct" it with the minimum amount of plastic surgery, I might suggest something like:

> 「健康のために、たばこ**は**吸わず、あまりお酒**も**飲まず、よく運動する**ようにしています**。」

The next one would probably be too much trimming, but to avoid using 「ず」 multiple times, one could say:

> 「健康のために、タバコ**や**お酒**は(or を)**[控]{ひか}え、よく運動するようにしています。」

You may just disregard my second sentence.